# Why is my program outputting 178 instead of 183?"

Tags: python

Write a program to calculate how many months it will take you to save up enough money for a down
payment. You will want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user inputs to floats.
**Your program should ask the user to enter the following variables:**

1. The starting annual salary (annual_salary)
2. The portion of salary to be saved (portion_saved)
3. The cost of your dream home (total_cost)
4. Call the cost of your dream home total_cost.
5. Call the portion of the cost needed for a down payment portion_down_payment. For
   simplicity, assume that portion_down_payment = 0.25 (25%).
6. Call the amount that you have saved thus far current_savings. You start with a current
   savings of $0.
7. Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of r (in other words,
   at the end of each month, you receive an additional current_savings*r/12 funds to put into
   your savings – the 12 is because r is an annual rate). Assume that your investments earn a
   return of r = 0.04 (4%).
8. Assume your annual salary is annual_salary.
9. Assume you are going to dedicate a certain amount of your salary each month to saving for
   the down payment. Call that portion_saved. This variable should be in decimal form (i.e. 0.1
   for 10%).
10. At the end of each month, your savings will be increased by the return on your investment,
    plus a percentage of your monthly salary (annual salary / 12).

Expected case

```
Enter your annual salary: 120000 
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .10
Enter the cost of your dream home: 1000000
Number of months: 183
```

My code text output

```
Number of months = 178
```

```
r = 0.04
current_savings = 0
potion_down_payment = 0.25
annual_salary = input('Enter your annual salary: ')
print(int(annual_salary))
monthly_salary = (int(annual_salary) / 12)
potion_saved = input('Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: ')
print(float(potion_saved))
cost_dream_home = input('Enter the cost of your dream home : ')
print(int(cost_dream_home))
invest_return = ((float(r) * float(annual_salary)) / 12)
amount_to_save = (float(potion_down_payment) * int(cost_dream_home))
potion_saved_f = (float(monthly_salary) * float(potion_saved))
total_saved = (float(invest_return) + potion_saved_f)
number_of_months = (float(amount_to_save) // float(total_saved))
print(int(number_of_months))
```

Comment: @RinkeshP Yes, the question is "Why is my program outputting 178 instead of 183?" There's just no [mcve] or effort.

Comment: Perhaps a more useful question would be "how can I print the value of each variable" but the answer should be obvious. Try that, and see where the expected output deviates from what is being printed.

Comment: Tangentially, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I refactored your code slightly to demonstrate some debugging efforts: https://ideone.com/KRdTXn

Comment: (Perhaps notice also that the variable should be "portion", not "potion". :-)

Comment: Perhaps the real error here is that your formula should be more complex, i.e. calculate compound interest.

Comment: @tripleee, Thank you very much for the modification on my code. However, I expected to get Number of Months to save to be 183. I'm not sure what i am doing wrong that my code is outputting 178

Answer (score 0):

I did this quickly, but you need a while loop, like:

```
months = 0
target = 250000
monthly_save = 1000.0
saved = 0.0
rate = .04
subtotal = 0.0

while subtotal < target:
    saved += monthly_save
    subtotal = (subtotal + monthly_save) * (1+(rate/12))
    months += 1
    print(months), print(int(subtotal))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have more time now. I think that you are just lucky that your code came out so close to the expected answer because your computations are off base.  Unless you know of a better formula, you really need a loop in order to compute compound interest month by month. I have analyzed your method below.

```
invest_return = ((float(r) * float(annual_salary)) / 12)  #.04*120000/12=400
amount_to_save = (float(potion_down_payment) * int(cost_dream_home))#.25*1000000=250000
potion_saved_f = (float(monthly_salary) * float(potion_saved))#10000*.1=1000
total_saved = (float(invest_return) + potion_saved_f)      #400+1000
number_of_months = (float(amount_to_save) // float(total_saved))  #250000//1400 = 178
print(int(number_of_months))
```